# How to automatically set classpath and share with other team members?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, classpath, ivy

I used ivy in Eclipse, and I have set special configurations in the ivy settings, and the Eclipse .classpath has changed too.

Is there a way to set the configurations such that after I commit to the team branch, anyone who pulls from the branch would automatically get the same setting in their Eclipse without doing anything else?

All the method I found online so far requires other team members to do some modifications manually. Is there a way to automatically set the configurations when built?

Comment: Can't you commit `.project/.classpath` as well to you repository? I think that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Committing `.project` or `.classpath` might seem like a good idea but it's generally problematic, particularly when different team members have different versions of Eclipse, different plugin configurations or (horrors) somebody wants to use a different IDE.